# Spark CSV - escape comma in quotes

Tags: apache-spark

How do i escape comma in quotes when reading csv file in spark
Example

```
"LED Marquee ""W"" Wall Sign, 2 Colors (Battery Operated) - CRDA3735A"
```

If i applied the code below, it will read as two string. I only want it to be read as one string

```
tmp = spark.read.csv('test.csv',header = True, sep = ',')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35570603/dealing-with-commas-within-a-field-in-a-csv-file-using-pyspark

Comment: You can't without the data containing the comma having quotes

Comment: Your csv is ok (1 field) - Is there an option to tell Spark csv to handle the fields as quoted fields?

Comment: How many fields do you have in a CSV file? Is the line the only line in the input CSV file?