# Unable to fix a Pyspark: Error length of fields (%d)" % (len(obj), len(dataType.fields))

Tags: python, pyspark

I am relatively new to Pyspark. I am trying to figure one particular type of error which is bugging me.

```py
lines = sc.textFile('train.csv')
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

The train.csv is stored [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By0bAi7hOBAFcFgtUEdpLUFDQkk/view): It is a bit huge.

The first row contains the column information. For setting the schema from the first row of the data

```py
fields = [StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in lines.first().split(',')] # I am setting the schema here
schema = StructType(fields)
mstr_header = lines.filter(lambda l: "Country" in l) #Ihave seen the first row of the data, I want to remove it. Only the first row contains 'Country'
linesNoHeader = lines.subtract(mstr_header)

lines_df = linesNoHeader.map(lambda x: x.split(",")).toDF(schema) #make a dataframe
```

When I run `lines_df.count()`, PySpark throws an error saying,

> length of fields (%d)" % (len(obj), len(dataType.fields)))ValueError: Length of object (18) does not match with length of fields (17)

I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong. Apologies for the large datafile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is more or less clear from the error message: in your file, the first few lines contain 17 fields, but there are quite a few lines that contain more fields (actually not more fields but more commas that you expect when you just use `split`).

You can check this just using shell commands quite easily:

```
cat train.csv | awk -F ',' '{print NF-1, NR}' | grep -v "^16"
```

(which counts the number of `,` per line and discards the ones that don't have exactly 16, i.e. 17 fields).

First example is line 16807, which looks like this:

> 16805,PH,-1.0,A,2017-08-21
>   00:03:13,Generic,android_webkit,Android,"http://supertraff.com/l/32398308f0e2f715d41?vId=bmconv_20170820203313_6b3e1d81_172f_4fd6_8725_f8cc7522896d&sub=20386192139,8753761,5,3177&source=Unknown&test=a",112.198.101.161,False,,0.0,282,,4901.0,0.0

Look at the query of the url, which contains several `,`. Luckily your `csv` is standard and it has double quotes at the beginning and the end of the field to escape the `,`, thus you can read it e.g. using the databricks `csv` reader.

Take a look in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572274/3519000) for an example, or at the [documentation](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).

Answer (score -1):

Use semicolon delimiter... sometimes works.
But there will always be bad data.